# UIGestures for a Two Finger Swipe Down From Top To Bottom

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, multi-touch, cydia, tweak

Pretty much a Gesture to bring in a separate Menu class with the Gesture being a two finger swip/pull from the very top of the screen to the very bottom of the screen. All I need is the code for the rest of my tweak. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough.

but from what I understood, try UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecorgnizer

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];

gesture.edges = UIRectEdgeTop; //you can change it to whatever edge you want

[yourView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

}
-(void)handleGesture:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer* )arg {
//handle the gesture here

}
```